# JSON serialization formatting and readability

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I have this simple class:

```
[DataContract]
    class MyClass
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int Value { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int Amount { get; set; }
    }
```

And i am serializing it like this:

```
MyClass test1 = new MyClass { Name= "Product1", Value = 230, Amount = 22 };
            MyClass test2 = new MyClass { Name= "Product2", Value = 110, Amount = 10 };

            List<MyClass> MyList = new List<MyClass>() { test1, test2 };
        string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MyList);
        Console.Write(output);
```

This results in a single line, unlike the documentation. I want to produce a format like on the `JSON` wiki.

> [{"Name":"Product1","Value":230,"Amount":22},{"Name":"Product2","Value":110,"Am‌​ount":10}]

To something like this:

```
[
{
"Name":"Product1",
"Value":230,
"Amount":22
},
{"Name":"Product2"
,"Value":110,
"Am‌​ount":10
}
]
```

Comment: The `DataContractJsonSerializer` is meant for data *transport* and as such readability and formatting is not important. Have you considered using [Newtonsoft Json.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/json) instead?

Comment: I would prefer a build in .net solution but i have a look into Newtonsoft.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen How do i install an API like that and use it? The documentation does not seem to handle this. Do i just unpack it somewhere and point to the DLL as a reference within my solution?

Comment: @MennoGouw Use NuGet for a painless install of Json.Net.

Comment: @BrianRogers Yeah i just read something about that. One last question, once i referenced this to my solution and put this in dropbox, would i need to install JSON.NET on another system as well? I work on many different systems/locations so that is why i prefer a build in solution.

Comment: @MennoGouw Yes, you would need to distribute the Newtonsoft.Json.dll along with your executable code.  (No installer needed, just make sure the DLL is in the same folder as the other executable files.)

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I am getting the exact same results using "string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MyList);"

Comment: @MennoGouw `I am getting the exact same results` No it generates `[{"Name":"Product1","Value":230,"Amount":22},{"Name":"Product2","Value":110,"Amount":10}]`

Comment: @L.B Yes i wanted to correct that, edited the question. Still there is no formatting.

Comment: @MennoGouw then use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MyList, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);` See the second parameter

Comment: @L.B Exactly! Thanks. This should get updated: http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html